# How to stop text inside an <li> being truncated by the next <li>

Tags: internet-explorer-7, html-lists, internet-explorer-6

In this menu the right-hand edge of the last letters is being chopped off by the "transparent"
background of the "|" in the next list-item

```
<ul class="menu1">
<li>HOME</li><li>|</li><li>CONTACT</li><li>|</li><li>ABOUT</li><li>|<li><li>SERVICES</li>
</ul>
<div class="clear"></div>
```

this affects at least IE 6 and 7, maybe 8 as well.
I prepared a fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/zhirkovski/5LnRS/2/
so you can see what I mean, If you are using IE9/10 then you can still see the problem by clicking on the "compatibility view" in the url.

If anyone can help make the transparent background transparent again I would be grateful.

If I change the li to a span like this jsfiddle.net/zhirkovski/3KfYN/17 it solves the problem, but is there anyway I can do it and maintain the li's

Answer (score 0):

It's the letter spacing causing the problem.

Not sure how to fix it in IE and keep the -7px letter spacing, you could change letter-spacing down to -3px and get away with it though, not sure how important this is to you

Comment: I would like to keep the -7px letter spacing